# how to retrieve all the keys from pair type container in c++

Tags: c++

`std::pair<uint32_t, std::vector<float32>> myPair`

suppose,

```
myPair = { {1221, [234.1, 1235.6]}, 
           {5579, [56.9, 5780.0]}, 
           { 467, [69579.8, 7974.55]} }
```

the above-declared `myPair` is the object of the pair type container. So I need to retrieve only the keys from the above pair i.e., 1221, 5579, 467....etc

Comment: `pair.first`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair

Comment: *So I need to retrieve only the keys from the above pair* -- What exactly do you mean by "retrieve"?  Save all the values in a container?  Pass those values to a function?  You need to clarify, so that a suitable answer can be given.

Comment: to extract all the keys in the pair using iterator or loops

Comment: `myPair` appears to be more like a `std::vector<std::pair<uint32_t, std::vector<float32>>>`. If the "keys" are unique, perhaps a `std::map` is what you're looking for.

Comment: [`std::ranges::views::keys`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/keys_view)

Comment: 1221, 5579, 467 these are the keys in the myPair. So i need to retrieve these keys and compare with some other values. So i need these every specific index key.

Comment: @LakshmiChinta *to extract all the keys in the pair using iterator or loops* -- Here is the issue -- we don't know what you mean by "retrieve" or "extract".  If it's a simple `for` loop, then `for (auto& p : myPair) { p.first... }` does that -- but I get the feeling you are looking for more than that.  By you using `std::pair`, you must have been familiar with the `first` member, else you wouldn't have used `pair`.  If you didn't know about `first` and you used `pair`, your question is in danger of being downvoted as "not doing research".

Comment: You can use `for` loop and iterate over the pairs and get keys by `itr.first`.

Comment: std::vector<std::map<int32_t, std::string>> data;                                                                                                         here data is the vector type and std::pair<uint32_t, std::vector<float32>> myPair; Here, I am extracting the 0th index value is nothing but map<key, value> so i am extracting only the map key and the in the myPair, i am extracting the 0th index of key so i need to compare these two values and like this i need to compare for all the values in the vector and myPair

Comment: for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(myPair); i++)
  { 
    i=0;
    for( auto x : data[i]  && auto y : myPair) 
    {
       uint32_t pairKey = y .first;
        CK_EQ(x.first,(int32_t)pairKey );
    }
  }                                                                                                                                                                            I mentioned like this, but its giving an compiler errors

Comment: `sizeof(myPair);` -- This is obviously wrong, and please post a [mcve].

Comment: no, its working correct in my terminal

Comment: It's wrong, you're just (un)lucky it is "working".  If you mean you want the number of items in a vector, `sizeof` does not give you this value.

Comment: @Lakshmi Chinta Edit your question and add these comments you just wrote to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this. You can change data types as per your need in my answer. And in for loop you can compare those key values as per your need

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<float>>> myPairs = 
        { {1221, {  234.1F, 1235.6F}}, 
          {5579, {   56.9F, 5780.0F}}, 
          { 467, {69579.8F, 7974.55F}} };

    for (const auto& p : myPairs) {
        std::cout << p.first << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i have already tried this, it didn't work in my end

Comment: for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(myPair); i++)
  { 
    i=0;
    for( auto x : data[i]  && auto y : myPair) 
    {
       uint32_t pairKey = y .first;
        CK_EQ(x.first,(int32_t)pairKey );
    }
  }      here data is the std::vector<map<int32_t, std::string>> is there any mistakes in the above code

Comment: try with `auto`

Comment: where should i try in the code?

Comment: you can just use my answer. change data types if you need where the vector is declared.

Comment: you know that `auto` does not resolve to reference? it's `const auto&`, `auto&&` or `auto&`

Comment: yes, but keys are needed only for comparison purposes. hence auto should be useful in this case.

Comment: @virteanchi you end up **copying** each `pair<int, vector<float>>` for each iteration

Comment: okay, I will have to read about it. Is the answer good now?

Comment: yes. Now it is correct

Answer (score 1):

You could also leverage the STL to do this rather easily with a lambda and `std::transform`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<pair<int, vector<float>>> myPairs =
        { {1221, {  234.1, 1235.6 }},
          {5579, {   56.9, 5780.0 }},
          { 467, {69579.8, 7974.55}} };
    vector<int> keys;

    transform(myPairs.cbegin(), myPairs.cend(), back_inserter(keys),
              [](const auto &pair) { return pair.first; });

    for (const auto &k : keys) 
        cout << k << endl;
}
```